# How to print row of choice mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table called `category` Inside this table lets say i have several rows 0 to 7 and inside the table i have `cat_id` and `cat_name`. How would i be able to print out `cat_name` based on whichever row i want. For example i want to print row 6 or 4 would i put it like $row[6] or $row[4]

Basically i want to use `. $_GET['rownumber']` to get the row number and then use it to print out the row. So would it work something like `$row[$_GET['rownumber']]` ? Im kind of confused just trying to learn mysql here.

I basically want to print the `cat_name` within that row that i choose in php

Comment: So do you need help with MySQL or php?

Comment: I want to use php to print it

Comment: Show us what you've tried first, please.

Comment: I havent tried anything yet because im not sure how to implement this.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to make this work but my idea was like $row[numberofrowhere];

Comment: You should select only the categories you need based on that $_GET var.. and then print all the results

Comment: I basically want to print the cat_name within that row that i choose

Comment: So you don't even know how to interact with the database at all?  Surely you at least have -something-.

Comment: Well i know how to print out all rows but not one specific row of my chosing.

Comment: I looked around but cant find anything around that shows how to print a row you want.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=PHP+and+MySQL+tutorial

Comment: @soniccool You could have started by at least posting what you've got now.

Comment: i dont have anything i am trying to learn what to do here

Comment: You have database interaction.  That, by definition, is -something-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to get the rows based on the row number:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
Select sub.*, sub.rank as Rank
FROM
(
   Select *,  (@rownum:=@rownum+1) as rowNum
   FROM   Categories
) sub
WHERE rowNum IN (4, 6)
```

However, Mysql has a built in function `ORDER BY LIMIT` to do this.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to read tonight ._.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_categories = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['categories']); // where categories can take values as 1 or 1,2,3

$query = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name 
          FROM categories 
          WHERE cat_id 
            IN (" . $my_categories . ")";

$sql = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
      echo $row['cat_name'];
   }
}
```

Comment: The check for mysql_num_rows is unnecessary as the while loop would just never execute because there is no data from mysql_fetch_array.  (and because I know someone will mention it -- the mysql library is deprecated in favor of the mysqli library -- I'm guilty as well :)

Comment: I put it there just in case he wants to print out a message if nothing is returned

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things at play here.

1) you say you are trying to learn mysql.  If you know the data you want, then you need to run a sql query that gets you all of the data you need and only the data you need.  You can filter the data you need using a WHERE clause.  google "mysql where" for more help on that.

2) You need to understand how databases work and how php handles them.  You can kind of think of them as rows and each row has certain columns (much like a spreadsheet).  Now with php the most common thing is to iterate over all of the rows one at a time because 1 row is considered one record.  php (generally) handles each row as an associated array (indexed by keywords).  The rows are typically iterated over using an iterator object (not indexable).  To do this (using the deprecated mysql library --I'm not comfortable enough with the current mysqli library) do the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
//iterate over all rows one at a time.
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($row["isDesiredRecord"]==true){
        echo $row["fieldName"]; //print whatever data you need from that row.
    }
}
```